# C error: control reaches end of non void function

Tags: c

I'm new here and I hope you can help me with an assignment I have to do for my programming lesson. The Task was to create a climate Control that shall cool the room if there is >22.2C°, heat it up when there's <18.5C° and do nothing if the temperature is in between.
The Code I made is:

```
/*
Compile: make climate_control1
Run: ./climate_control1
*/

#include "base.h"

/*
Eine Klimaanlage soll bei Temperaturen unter 18.5 °C heizen, bei 18.5-22.2 °C nichts tun und bei Temperaturen ab 22.2 °C kühlen.
Entwickeln Sie eine Funktion zur Regelung der Klimaanlage, die abhängig von der Temperatur heizt, ausschaltet oder kühlt.
*/

enum TemperatureStage {
    LOW_TEMPERATURE,
    HIGH_TEMPERATURE
};

typedef int Degree; // int represents temperature in degree celsius

const  Degree LOW_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY  = 18.5; // interpret.: Temperature in degree celsius.
const  Degree HIGH_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY = 22.2; // interpret.: Temperature in degree celsius.

//Degree -> Degree.

Degree climate_control(Degree degree);


void climate_control_test() {
    check_expect_i(climate_control(LOW_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY),0);
    check_expect_i(climate_control(HIGH_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY), 0);
    check_expect_i(climate_control(10), LOW_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY);
    check_expect_i(climate_control(20.6), 0);
    check_expect_i(climate_control(33), HIGH_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY);

}

// regulate the temperature.

Degree climate_control(Degree degree) {
    if (degree == LOW_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY) {
        return 0;
    } else if (degree < LOW_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY) { 
    return LOW_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY; }
     else if (degree == HIGH_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY) {
        return 0;
    } else if (degree > HIGH_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY) { 
    return HIGH_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY; }
}




int main (void) {
    climate_control_test();
    return 0;
}
```

The error "control reaches end of non void function" appears every time i try to compile it. I have no idea what's wrong with it. I Need to say that I had nearly no experiences in coding before I started studying 3 weeks ago.

Comment: This is obviously not C#... You should know what language are you using

Comment: `Degree climate_control(Degree degree)` should have a plain `else` statement in case none of the `if`'s get hit (which is what is happening). The compiler doesn't evaluate your code paths,it just knows that there is a chance that your `if` statements all fall through, reaching the end of that function without returning anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your function has a possible code path that lets the if's fall through without the function returning anything. Technically it shouldn't be possible, but the compiler has noticed the possibility, and won't let you continue. Your function should look more like this:

```
Degree climate_control(Degree degree) {
    if (degree == LOW_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY) {
        return 0;
    } else if (degree < LOW_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY) { 
    return LOW_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY; }
    else if (degree == HIGH_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY) {
        return 0;
    } else if (degree > HIGH_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY) { 
    return HIGH_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY; }

    return 0;
}
```

Why does the compiler think this? What would happen to the above code if some brain-dead (or drunk) programmer did this:

```
const  Degree LOW_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY  = 18.5; 
const  Degree HIGH_TEMPERATURE_BOUNDARY = -22.2;  //Notice the sign change?
```

Now your `climate_control` function will fall through.